# Sql query to get total orders amount by weeks of current year

Tags: sql-server

I have a table name "Orders".

I want to calculate total orders amount by weeks of current month.

Currently I am able to get total orders by months using below query :-

```
SELECT 
                    "Month" = month(o.OrderDate)
                     , "Year" = year(o.OrderDate)
                     , Amount = sum(o.Total)
                FROM
                    Orders o
                WHERE
                    o.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                    AND o.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                GROUP BY
                    month(o.OrderDate)
                  , year(o.OrderDate)
                ORDER BY
                    year(o.OrderDate)
                  , month(o.OrderDate)
```

But now I want to get this data by weeks like bellow :-

As we have about 52 weeks in each year so data should be like these :-

Week   Year   Amount
  1    2013     200
  2    2013     500
.......
  52   2013      0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to get the week number.

To get rows for each week even if there are no registration in that week you can use a [numbers table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) and left join on to your orders table.

This query will give you the year `2013` that happens to have `53` weeks.

```
select N.Number as [Week],
       2013 as [Year],
       sum(O.Total) as Amount
from dbo.Numbers as N
  left outer join dbo.Orders as O    
    on n.Number = datepart(week, O.OrderDate) and
       O.OrderDate >= '20130101' and
       O.OrderDate < '20140101'
where n.Number between 1 and 53
group by N.Number
order by N.Number;
```

If you don't have or want to create a numbers table you can use this instead that will create one for you in the query.

```
select N.Number as [Week],
       2013 as [Year],
       sum(O.Total) as Amount
from (
     select top (53) row_number() over(order by 1/0) as Number
     from sys.all_objects
     ) as N
  left outer join dbo.Orders as O    
    on n.Number = datepart(week, O.OrderDate) and
       O.OrderDate >= '20130101' and
       O.OrderDate < '20140101'
where n.Number between 1 and 53
group by N.Number
order by N.Number;
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikael for your quick response, where should I put this DATEPART ? In select list or in where clause?

Comment: @AnandMeena In the group by if you want to group by week and calculate the sum by week.

Comment: @AnandMeena Not necessary. You have the code in your question already. Just change `month(o.OrderDate)` to `DATEPART(wk, o.OrderDate)`.

Comment: Yes I did, but it is not giving desire result, as I want each week data. Means in 1 year we have 52 weeks, but with these it is only returning 7 rows, but there should be 52 rows.

Comment: @AnandMeena What version of SQL Server is this for?

Comment: sqlserver R2 2008, thanks. Also please have a look on screen shot, I posted on Nitu's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but still something wrong here. Have a look on http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/032d4b0c-1dd5-476c-b2c8-f6b8cbbf6d07/47f53a0abaaf005cbc449a2904ab98d9 , It is not giving result for weeks 2,3,4,6,7 etc

Comment: @AnandMeena What is wrong. I can't guess by that picture. Do you want a 0 instead of null in Amount?

Comment: I means, why second week is NULL here?, its a second week on January, right?. Then there must be some value for it.

Comment: @AnandMeena I can't see your data but by the looks of it you have no data in the second week of January.

Comment: @AnandMeena  BTW you really should use the date format I used because it will work regardless of language settings in SQL Server. And if you want data from the last day of the year you should use '20140101' as the end date.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael, It is working fine, there is no entry for 2,3,4 week in database. Now I want to show o instead of NULL, can you help?

Comment: @AnandMeena `isnull(sum(O.Total), 0) as Amount`

Answer (score 2):

please try as below

```
           SELECT 
                 DATEPART (wk, o.OrderDate)as week,                    
                 year(o.OrderDate) as year
                 , Amount = sum(o.Total)
            FROM
                Orders o
            WHERE
                o.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
                AND o.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
            GROUP BY
                DATEPART(wk, o.OrderDate)
              , year(o.OrderDate)
            ORDER BY
                year(o.OrderDate)
              , DATEPART(wk, o.OrderDate)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitu, But it is giving different result, have a look on screen shot http://www.evernote.com/shard/s364/sh/2b36a82b-4358-4a64-b108-c115edc66bb0/63878b05f031aa81100c0459bc84ea10, I want 1,2,3,4,5 instead of 1,5,9,14 ...

Comment: you can take a number table having value from 1...53 and left outer join with this table,it will result 0 for week you have no data.

Answer (score 0):

please try this
you can take a number table having value from 1...53 and left outer join with this table,it will result 0 for week you have no data.

```
       select numbers.value,numbers.[Year],amt from numbers left outer join (
        SELECT 
             DATEPART (wk, o.OrderDate)as week,                    
             2013 as [Year],
             ,sum(o.Total)as amt
        FROM
            Orders o
        WHERE
            o.OrderDate >= convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM')
            AND o.OrderDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013 12:00:00 AM')
        GROUP BY
            DATEPART(wk, o.OrderDate)
          , year(o.OrderDate)
        ORDER BY
            year(o.OrderDate)
          , DATEPART(wk, o.OrderDate)
      )data on data.week=numbers.value
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: please remove "Amount =" in 5th line